# How to send information from Next.js application to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, next.js, google-chrome-extension

I have an application. I want to debug this application and for this reason I want to build a Chrome Extension. I somehow want to send an information from my application and catch that information on chrome extension.

Now we only have that information on app's console.log, but we want to send this info this to chrome extension. Is this possible to do?

I found out this:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage
But I am not sure if it is right thing that I am looking for, and didn't understand how to use.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage') I get this error message. Trying to find a solution. Do you know about this?

Comment: It usually means you didn't add externally_connectable as shown in the article or didn't reload the extension or didn't reload the tab.